# StackOverflowError while processing large file with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, large-files, stack-overflow

I have the following code:

```
 String regex = "Some String(.*\r?\n)*.*\\* testing .*\r?\n.*\r?\n.*children.*\r?\n";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
 System.out.println(p.pattern());
 String content = readFile(); // it return file content
 Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
```

So when I test with a small file content it works fine. But with a large file content it gives the following error with my code:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    ...
```

I think the regex engine is creating problem. This may be because of the nested quantifier. So can anybody optimize my regular expression, in such a way that the regex engine process it easily?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to match?

Comment: And what version of java?

Comment: You're using a lot of greedy quantifiers (`.*`)... the first thing I would try is converting them into reluctant ones (`*?`). Even better would be to constrain the `.` to `[^\r\n]`.

Comment: Are you aware of what `.` does **not** match?

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is that your regex expression is matching too many lines. Since you have:

```
\r?\n
```

several times in your record, it can match to multiple lines.

So:

```
"Some String(.*\r?\n)*.*\\* testing .*\r?\n.*\r?\n.*children.*\r?\n"
```

would match

```
Some String


\ testing



children


Some String
```

You would need to find an expression that finishes each record, otherwise the regex engine would be able to match from the first until the last record and that could break.

This theory is shown in the stack trace, where you have several stack trace blocks duplicated with this one:

```
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4683)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3715)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Ques.match(Pattern.java:4079)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4170)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4132)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
```